# JAX-RS resource in Tomcat not getting called

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, jax-rs

I'm learning Java. I ran a simple maven Jersey project on Tomcat with IntelliJ, the results are:

http://localhost:8080/demorest_war/
-> renders the index.jsp

http://localhost:8080/demorest_war/webresources/myresource
-> reports: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

[image]
the basic resource code and configuration are:

```
src/main/webapp/index.jsp
--------------------------
<html>
<body>
<h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
<p><a href="webresources/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
<p>Visit the <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
for more information on Jersey!
</body>
</html>

src/main/java/com/telusko/MyResource.java
-------------------------------------------
package com.telusko;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {
    @GET 
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIt() {
        return "Hi there!";
    }
}


src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
----------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.telusko</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

There was no errors or exceptions on the console during the build or processing the requests.

could anyone help identify what might be the cause?
also, where is the "demorest_war" part of the URL is configured?

Comment: Use Jersey 3.x.. and look for docs for 3.x. Or change to Tomcat 9

Comment: I'd like to ask a further question: how do I know which Tomcat version I should choose for a particular project?

Comment: Tomcat 10 uses new Jakarta namespace. Google "Java EE to Jakarta EE"

Comment: Kindly upgrade your Tomcat to at least version 10. This is due to compatibility with Jersey version you choose.